# Can I see the active Cucumber options from within a Ruby step definition?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'd like my step definition to have conditional behavior based on cuke's run-time options.  For example, I don't want my step to print terminal color codes if `cucumber` was executed with `--no-color`.

Is there any way that I can programmatically see the cucumber run-time options from within the step definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to access all the run-time options, but you can access the current coloring option via `Cucumber::Term::ANSIColor.coloring?`.

Comment: That is actually perfect for what I need!  It'd be nice to have the other stuff, but this nails my need.